# Grub Rescue Desktop PC completely broken

Tags: grub, rescue

This is not a Dual OS, I only have a Linux Feren OS installed.

I was supposed to install Windows 7 onto it. It says I need to create a partition for Win 7 Installation. Next I hop into Command prompt and create 2 partitions. I accidentally set it to occupy the whole HDD and I deleted it. I think that might be the problem.

I've restarted the PC and now I'm here at Grub Rescue.

Also there is no CD/DVD drive, only USB ports.

I've tried the `ls` command, it only shows up one HDD with one partition and it's unknown filesystem. Also tried `set prefix, boot, root` no help. Also `insmod normal` doesn't work because it is an unknown filesystem.

If I can somehow boot the PC up using an USB stick, I already formatted my stick to an **ext2 filesystem** and it recognizes it. Only problem I have is that there are no files on that stick. I wonder how to copy files into an **ext2 filesystem** USB stick.

I can't get past Grub Rescue, and can't enter BIOS or anything other.

Comment: Do you want to restorte the system or are fine with rescuing data?

Comment: @FelixJN I want to restore the system, I don't need the data, when restored, then I want to install Win 7 onto it

Comment: Just reinstall the system. Next time don't delete the partition table.

Comment: @paladin I don't think I can just reinstall the system. I can't open boot menu or BIOS and the Grub Rescue doesn't offer many commands and also I can't find the grub directory that should be on the hd1

Comment: Why can't you enter BIOS (which would have had to be present to even get as far as grub)?